# Возникает ошибка при установке библиотеки pycocotools в PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, библиотеки

Возникает ошибка при установке библиотеки pycocotools в PyCharm:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

версия PyCharm 2020.1.3
версия Python3 3.8.3

Comment: Это все сообщение об ошибке? Пробовали в терминале установить руками через pip?

Comment: на самом деле это не все сообщения, и в PyCharm  и через pip сообщение одинаковое и достаточно объемное, все не поместиться в поле коментария

Comment: cl: Є®¬ ­¤­ п бва®Є  error D8021: ­Ґ¤®ЇгбвЁ¬л© зЁб«®ў®©  аЈг¬Ґ­в "/Wno-cpp"
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\alexey.durakov\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o2iod0h9\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\alexey.durakov\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o2iod0h9\\pycocotools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record

Comment: 'C:\Users\alexey.durakov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r47jjjh4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python3\Include\pycocotools' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: вот эти коментарии идут в конце

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему пути, у вас Windows.
Pycocotools не поддерживает Windows.